# location map on careers company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The location map on the company page shows a general location if you put the city - (I'm guessing city hall).

Dragging the pin manually doesn't stick.

Entering the exact street address shows the correct location. But so large scale (a single block) as to be useless to anyone looking outside the area.

Comment: Manually dragging the pin normally works; there's a bug that I'm working to fix right now. Stay tuned!